# sorting eBay categoryHistogram results

Tags: php, sorting, ebay-api

I need help sorting the results from my findItemsAdvanced call. Specifically, I'm trying to sort the child categories from eBay's CategoryHistogramContainer.  Here's my code to display the histogram in the default sort order, which is by descending item count.

```
foreach ($resp->categoryHistogramContainer->categoryHistogram->childCategoryHistogram as $category) {

  echo $category->categoryName . ' (' . $category->count . ') <br />';

}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
usort(ARRAY, array(new cmpArray("ARRAY_INDEX_TO_SORT"), "asccmp__"));
class cmpArray
{
    var $key;
    function __construct($key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
    }
    function asccmp__($a, $b)
    {
        $key = $this->key;
        if($a[$key] == $b[$key])
            return 0;

        return (($a[$key] > $b[$key]) ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```